# Extract table name from insert, update or delete statement using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Does anyone know of a way to extract the table name from any T-SQL insert, update or delete statement? As an example, given this statement (in the form of a simple string):

```
'Update MyTable Set MyColumn = 10 Where Column1 = 4'
```

'MyTable' would be returned.

The method would also have to account for a more complicated Update statement such as:

```
'Update T Set T.MyColumn = 4
From MyTable T
   Inner Join ...
...'
```

The SQL statement would be in the form of a string and this process would parse the string and return the table name.

What I'm looking for is something similar to `sp_describe_first_result_set` except, of course, sp_describe_first_result_set only works for Select statements. And I just need the table name.

Comment: sounds like a trigger dumping references "mytable" to a table

Comment: You want to pass a statement as string and return table name? please it's not clear what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Sami - I have clarified what I want to do.

Comment: How are these statements stored?  As .sql files?  In stored procedures?  In functions?

Comment: @n8. - See my post. I said the SQL statement would be in the form of a string.

Comment: @RandyMinder detect for example `from`, `update` ... which the table name should be.

Comment: @Sami --- What?

Comment: The reason I ask is because Russell's answer (or something very like it) is the best that SQL has to offer and it's just bad.  This is more easily accomplished on another layer, like OO (less messy and probably more performant).  SQL can't make use of table names unless you're using dynamic SQL but if it's already arriving as a string you might as well build and execute it external from SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can do it with some awful-looking string parsing (sample data included, in case someone else can do better). You should be able to just run this in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @sql TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, SQLString VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @sql
        ( SQLString )
VALUES  ('Update MyTable Set MyColumn = 10 Where Column1 = 4')
    , ('Update T Set T.MyColumn = 4 From MyOtherTable T    Inner Join MyOtherTable O    ON t.id = o.id;') 
    , ('SELECT * FROM Triskaidekaphobia WHERE [foo] = ''bar'';')

SELECT SQLString
    , FirstTableName = 
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('FROM', SQLString) > 0
            THEN 
                SUBSTRING(
                    SQLString, --expression
                    CHARINDEX('FROM ', SQLString) + 5, --start
                    CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(SQLString, CHARINDEX('FROM ', SQLString) + 5, 255))-1 --length
                )
            ELSE 
                SUBSTRING(
                    SQLString, 
                    CHARINDEX('UPDATE ', SQLString) + 7, 
                    CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(SQLString, CHARINDEX('UPDATE ', SQLString) + 7, 255))-1
                )
        END
FROM @sql
```

Comment: That's an interesting start. Thank you.